# Is there any Whatsapp messenger for elementary os?

Tags: thirdpartyapps

I have been using rambox for whatsapp. But is there any alternative clients which are still working?

Comment: I think you can use whatsapp web client as webapp in epiphany browser, at least for messages (not sure about calls and i don't have/want account to test it)

Comment: As far as i know there is no .deb file dor whatsdesk. If you don't want to use the snap version check whatsie, some more info here: https://www.google.com/amp/www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/amp/whatsie-install-use-whatsapp-in-linux Edit: alternatively you might use ephipany to create a web app, go to the site, cliock on the gear on the top right and select "save as web app".

Answer (score 2):

The best client I found for Whatsapp only is [whatsdesk](https://snapcraft.io/whatsdesk)

Alternatives for it:

- Extensions for chrome (or the browser you use). In chrome's case, there are extensions that can be installed as a system application
- Multiservices applications such as Rambox or Franz

Answer (score 1):

I find a few snap packages [HERE](https://snapcraft.io/search?q=what)

I haven't tried any but they probably work, so why no try

> sudo apt-get install snapd
>   sudo snap install package-name

If you install Opera Browser it got a plugins/tab (really idk what it's) but it has it by default, plus you have a "free" VPN service an a ad blocker. ALL by default

[image]

Comment: Yeah....but I was looking at an alternative like desktop client and not a add on..thanks anyway

Comment: @CharithReddy I was looking for another solution, it looks that some people make like a shorcut from Google Chrome to and "Desktop App" so maybe you can give a chance

https://itsfoss.com/whatsapp-linux-desktop/

Comment: Actually I already saw that post.....but the thing is there are no links available

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Firefox you can use the whatsapp addon

Comment: Yeah....but I was looking at an alternative like desktop client and not a add on..thanks anyway